# Android data binding not generated, cannot see subfolders

Tags: android, android-studio, mvvm, android-databinding

After implementing MVVM with data binding into my project, everything worked fine initially, then i decided to move my custom viewModel class to a subfolder called "ViewModels", then when I tried to rebuild the project it failed with error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
import com.example.myproject.ViewModels;
                                 ^
  symbol:   class ViewModels
  location: package com.example.myproject
```

I'm using Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1, how do i fix this?

**Note:** I already tried cleaning the project and rebuilding and invalidating cache and restart. They didn't work.

Comment: This sometimes happen when the classes are not refactored properly, try moving the class in another package and then moving back to current package again. This should probably work.